# Extracting between specific <script> </script> tag

Tags: python, lxml

I am able to extract all the  tags with the following code. However, I don't know how to look inside between the `<script>` and `</script>` tag. In particular, say I wanted just this part (there is more in between but I am not interested in that) :

```
<script>
            var quoteDataObj = [{"symbol":"CLCV1","symbolType":"symbol","code":0,"name":"WTI Crude Oil (Jun\u002715)","shortName":"OIL","last":"59.54","exchange":"New York Mercantile Exchange","source":"","open":"60.69","high":"61.31","low":"59.14","change":"-1.39","currencyCode":"USD","timeZone":"EDT","volume":"189607","provider":"CNBC Quote Cache","altSymbol":"CL/M5","curmktstatus":"REG_MKT","realTime":"false","assetType":"DERIVATIVE","noStreaming":"false","encodedSymbol":"CLCV1"}]
</script>
```

Not sure what code I need to add to this? I need to get the comma separated stuff between the `[{` and `}]` into a python dictionary.

**EDIT** to take the suggestion in the answer:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu May  7 10:31:02 2015

@author: idf
"""

import re
import json
import urllib2
from lxml import etree 


url='http://data.cnbc.com/quotes/CLCV1'

def wgetUrl(target):
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(target)
        req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3 Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3')
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        outtxt = response.read()
        response.close()
    except:
        return ''

    return outtxt

def extract_text(elem):        
    if elem is None:
        print None
    else:
        return ''.join(i for i in elem.itertext())

content = wgetUrl(url)
node = etree.HTML(content)
parser = etree.HTMLParser()


nodes = node.findall(r'.//script')
for x in nodes:
    matches = re.findall(r'quoteDataObj\s\=\s(\[.+\])', x)
    if len(matches) > 0:
        python_dict = json.loads(matches[0])
```

Comment: if you've ever found `urllib2` too clunky, have a look at [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex on the script to find the `quoteDataObj` variable and load its contents with JSON. Example:

```
import re
import json

#...your code...

content = wgetUrl(url)
matches = re.findall(r'quoteDataObj\s\=\s\[(\{.+\})\]', content)
if len(matches) > 0:
    python_dict = json.loads(matches[0])
```

Output:

```
{u'altSymbol': u'CL/M5',
 u'assetType': u'DERIVATIVE',
 u'change': u'-1.39',
 u'code': 0,
 u'curmktstatus': u'REG_MKT',
 u'currencyCode': u'USD',
 u'encodedSymbol': u'CLCV1',
 u'exchange': u'New York Mercantile Exchange',
 u'high': u'61.31',
 u'last': u'59.54',
 u'low': u'59.14',
 u'name': u"WTI Crude Oil (Jun'15)",
 u'noStreaming': u'false',
 u'open': u'60.69',
 u'provider': u'CNBC Quote Cache',
 u'realTime': u'false',
 u'shortName': u'OIL',
 u'source': u'',
 u'symbol': u'CLCV1',
 u'symbolType': u'symbol',
 u'timeZone': u'EDT',
 u'volume': u'189607'}
```

### Using LXML parsing

The OP expressed interest in seeing how the problem could be solved with LXML parsing. Here it is:

```
import re
import json

#...your code...

for x in nodes:
    matches = re.findall(r'quoteDataObj\s\=\s\[(\{.+\})\]', str(x.text))
    if len(matches) > 0:
        python_dict = json.loads(matches[0])
```

Comment: I added your code but I get an error:  File "/home/idf/anaconda/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 181, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)

TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: ah sorry I thought `x` from `nodes` was a string or buffer. Hold on let me check what the type is.

Comment: no worries. The above code actually runs you can copy and paste it and try it. I wrote extract_text function but I can't get it to work either.

Comment: ok so I edited my answer. No need to parse the page for all the script elements. It now regex's the entire page for that variable and if it finds a match loads the content into "python_dict"

Comment: Thanks. That works. It would be nice to see how it is done in a more "parsing way" through lxml.  But you got it.

Comment: One thing, on mine it has an extra [ ] around the dict? You meant python_dict[0]

Comment: Damn. I tried a few different things and uploaded the wrong one. The regex query should be `quoteDataObj\s\=\s\[(\{.+\})\]` which will only grab the json object within the array. I'll change the answer again.

Answer (score 2):

## Let JSON do the Heavy Lifting

I'm going to assume that the format of the content you want is like your example:

```
<script>
            var quoteDataObj = [{"symbol":"CLCV1","symbolType":"symbol","code":0,"name":"WTI Crude Oil (Jun\u002715)","shortName":"OIL","last":"59.54","exchange":"New York Mercantile Exchange","source":"","open":"60.69","high":"61.31","low":"59.14","change":"-1.39","currencyCode":"USD","timeZone":"EDT","volume":"189607","provider":"CNBC Quote Cache","altSymbol":"CL/M5","curmktstatus":"REG_MKT","realTime":"false","assetType":"DERIVATIVE","noStreaming":"false","encodedSymbol":"CLCV1"}]
</script>
```

In this case, we can actually treat the `quoteDataObj` value as json.

Thus the simplest way to deal with this would be like so:

```
>>> text
'            var quoteDataObj = [{"symbol":"CLCV1","symbolType":"symbol","code":0,"name":"WTI Crude Oil (Jun\\u002715)","shortName":"OIL","last":"59.54","exchange":"New York Mercantile Exchange","source":"","open":"60.69","high":"61.31","low":"59.14","change":"-1.39","currencyCode":"USD","timeZone":"EDT","volume":"189607","provider":"CNBC Quote Cache","altSymbol":"CL/M5","curmktstatus":"REG_MKT","realTime":"false","assetType":"DERIVATIVE","noStreaming":"false","encodedSymbol":"CLCV1"}]'
>>> data = text[ text.index('[')+1 : text.rindex(']') ]
>>> data
'{"symbol":"CLCV1","symbolType":"symbol","code":0,"name":"WTI Crude Oil (Jun\\u002715)","shortName":"OIL","last":"59.54","exchange":"New York Mercantile Exchange","source":"","open":"60.69","high":"61.31","low":"59.14","change":"-1.39","currencyCode":"USD","timeZone":"EDT","volume":"189607","provider":"CNBC Quote Cache","altSymbol":"CL/M5","curmktstatus":"REG_MKT","realTime":"false","assetType":"DERIVATIVE","noStreaming":"false","encodedSymbol":"CLCV1"}'
>>> import json
>>> values = json.loads(data)
>>> values
{u'code': 0, u'realTime': u'false', u'symbolType': u'symbol', u'high': u'61.31', u'open': u'60.69', u'assetType': u'DERIVATIVE', u'currencyCode': u'USD', u'source': u'', u'low': u'59.14', u'provider': u'CNBC Quote Cache', u'exchange': u'New York Mercantile Exchange', u'symbol': u'CLCV1', u'volume': u'189607', u'curmktstatus': u'REG_MKT', u'encodedSymbol': u'CLCV1', u'shortName': u'OIL', u'change': u'-1.39', u'altSymbol': u'CL/M5', u'last': u'59.54', u'name': u"WTI Crude Oil (Jun'15)", u'noStreaming': u'false', u'timeZone': u'EDT'}
```

Comment: Thanks. The question is how to get this particular data inside the script tags. Once we have the var... text, it is easy to extract the data.